# Compute pointwise proportion of distribution greater than a second

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

Trying to figure out the math of some code I've inherited that wasn't commented.

Basically, there are two inverse gaussian functions with different means and equal variance over 1000 time points

The line of code computes for each t point the proportion of distribution 1 that is greater than or equal to distribution two. This is done by taking a pointwise division of distribution 1 ./ (1 + e^(1000*(1000-t)).

If anyone could explain where the exponential comes from/what this is accomplishing, this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "inverse gaussian function"--that has several possible interpretations.  And could you explain what you mean by a "pointwise division of distribution"?  That is perhaps a little too vague to convey what's going on.

Comment: The inverse gaussian is a normal distribution in the time domain transformed to the rate domain for reaction time analysis.

Pseudo-code for second comment
pTR2(j,:) = pTR./(1+exp(length(t)*(t-j)))

where pTR is the inverse-gaussian

Comment: Thank you, but that makes things even more mysterious.  Transformed how?  Are you perhaps describing the [Inverse Gaussian distribution?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)  And what is the relationship between your "x" and the "t" in your formula?

Comment: Yes, inverse gaussian distribution. t an x was an oversight, edited for clarity

Comment: Okay, could you explain what "proportion of distribution" might mean?  Perhaps you could supply a formula?  That would help eliminate much the ambiguity.

Comment: That's a logistic function, but it's very hard to guess what might be going on from this.